# Jenkinsfile for Robotframework

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, robotframework

I'm facing issues in running jobs through Jenkinsfile. Right now the job runs up to build stage and after that, it fails for every stage. I've attache an image for the console output being received as well.

Searched everywhere but didn't got any solution, don't know where I'm making a mistake in the code.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

`````
        parameters {
            booleanParam(defaultValue: true, description: 'Execute Pipeline?', name: 'GO')
        }
        agent {label 'test'}
        stages {
            stage('Preconditions'){
                steps {
                    script {
                        result = sh (script: "git log -1 | grep ' _*\\[ci skip\\].*'", returnStatus: true)
                        if (result == 0) {
                            echo "This build should be skipped. Aborting"
                            GO = "false"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Build'){
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh "pip install -r requirements.txt"
                        sh "mkdir -p ${out}/results"
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Smoke') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh "robot -d results -i Smoke -v BROWSER:chrome test_suites"
                        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Sanity') {
                steps {
                    script {
                    sh "robot -d results -i Sanity -v BROWSER:chrome test_suites"
                    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Process Results') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        bat 'del "Results\\*.zip"'
                        zip zipFile: 'results/results.zip', archive: false, dir: 'results', glob: '*.html'
                        step([
                            $class : 'RobotPublisher',
                            outputPath : 'results',
                            outputFileName : "output.xml",
                            reportFileName : 'report.html',
                            logFileName : 'log.html',
                            disableArchiveOutput : false,
                            passThreshold : 95.0,
                            unstableThreshold: 95.0,
                            otherFiles : "**/*.png",
                            ])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        post {
            always {
                googlechatnotification url: 
            }
        }
    }````

The requirements.txt files contain all the bindings like: 
selenium==3.141.0
virtualenv==16.5.0
robotframework==3.1.1
robotframework-pabot==0.53
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1
robotframework-react==1.0.0a2

[![Console Output][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPPPz.png
`````

Comment: It fails before Smoke (first `robot` test).

Comment: @helio can you help me out with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I supect that the failing command is the creation of the `results` directory in the `Build` stage, because the variable `${out}` is in groovy syntax not shell:

```
stage('Build'){
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "pip install -r requirements.txt"
                    sh "mkdir -p ${out}/results"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Even after removing the output directory still, it's not running. Now there's another error "/script.sh: robot: not found"